# Django reverse error: invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'objectidXXXXXXX in string'

Tags: python, django, mongodb

I'm new to MongoDB/Django

I'm using `djongo` as shown below. I could save. But I'm get the error as title.

settings.py

```
DATABASES = {
    'default': {
        'ENGINE': 'djongo',
        'NAME': 'webpage',
    }
}
```

models.py

```
class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tests:test-detail', kwargs={'pk': self.pk})
```

Or

```
class Test(models.Model):
    title = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    content = models.TextField()

    def get_absolute_url(self):
        return reverse('tests:test-detail', kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)})
```

views.py

```
class TestDetailView(LoginRequiredMixin, DetailView):
    model = Test
```

urls.py

```
app_name = 'tests'

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<pk>/', TestDetailView.as_view(), name='test-detail'),
]
```

Or

```
app_name = 'tests'

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<str:pk>/', TestDetailView.as_view(), name='test-detail'),
]
```

Or

```
app_name = 'tests'

urlpatterns = [
    path('test/<int:pk>/', TestDetailView.as_view(), name='test-detail'),
]
```

When the code runs `get_absolute_url`, it returns error as below:

> **invalid literal for int() with base 10: 'objectidXXXXXXX in string'**

Comment: And if you'll try this? - `kwargs={'pk': str(self.pk)}`

Comment: Also tried it. No success.

Comment: in your url.py the pk is int not str. So it should look like <int:pk>

Comment: It is not int. Mongo primary key is ObjectID, not index by SQLite. Tried it before, doesn't work as supposed to be.